# Gatling scenario check the exact content of the response body

Tags: scala, gatling, scala-gatling

I'm sending a request like below and expect the body of the response to be `""` (see check below):

```scala
  val runGraphScn = scenario("runGraph Scenario")
    .exec(http("POST runGraph")
      .post("/runGraph")
      .body(InputStreamBody(getClass.getResourceAsStream("/rungraph_req_body.json")))
      .check(
        status is 200,
        bodyString is ""
      )
    )
```

But when I run the scenario I see it failing `bodyString.find.is(), found ""`

```
================================================================================
2020-07-24 17:09:20                                          55s elapsed
---- Requests ------------------------------------------------------------------
> Global                                                   (OK=1      KO=2     )
> POST runGraph                                            (OK=0      KO=1     )
> GET getProject                                           (OK=1      KO=0     )
> POST /runGraphResult                                     (OK=0      KO=1     )
---- Errors --------------------------------------------------------------------
> bodyString.find.is(), found ""                                      1 (50.00%)
> status.find.is(200), but actually found 404                         1 (50.00%)
```

How can I check that the response body is empty??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The body of your response is indeed `""`. Not empty, but literally the two quotation marks. The test will pass if your check is `bodyString is "\"\""`.

My guess is that in the server code you write, you `return`ed `""`, an empty string. And the HTTP framework json-encoded that and sent two double quotes in the response.

You can [turn on logging for Gatling](https://gatling.io/docs/current/general/debugging/#logback) to see more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce (tried with master branch) so I suspect you actually have some non printable char, either in your response body, or in your expected result.

Please check your Content-Length and your Simulation.

If that's not the issue, please provide a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/).

Side note regarding `InputStreamBody(getClass.getResourceAsStream("/rungraph_req_body.json"))`: overly complicated, you should just use `RawFileBody("rungraph_req_body.json")`.

Comment: My suspicion is the code written returned an empty string and the framework json-encoded that empty string to the body string of `""`.

Comment: @GeorgeLeung No, bodyString parses response body as a String for sure.

Comment: By "the framework" I don't mean the Gatling framework, but the HTTP framework the asker uses. I have a lot of confidence on the saneness of the Gatling framework.

Comment: A piece of evidence supporting my guess is the error message, which contains the quotation marks. They do not seem to be generated by Gatling, and is more likely what got sent over the wire.

Comment: @GeorgeLeung Oh, my bad, you're completely right! The response here is not empty String but `""` with a Content-Length of 2, otherwise Gatling would have printed `found `. Feel free to post your answer which is the correct one!

Comment: @StéphaneLANDELLE I saw `RawFileBody` in the documentation but didn't give it a try. I agree it is a lot better than my current hack.